# mysql setup with wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to configure LAMP on a local Ubuntu dev box.  I cannot seem to find any reliable docs about:

How to configure MySQL login info to support WordPress, and

How to set up a database suitable for WordPress.

If I google WordPress, I get hundreds of commercial links selling themes, plug-ins, and what-not, but no concise configuration info.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-lamp/ 
I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

First, install lamp server and configure it: https://do.co/2P9WBxn

Then install WordPress: https://do.co/2vMnnDU